# scons and ctags

Tags: tags, scons, ctags

I am trying to get ctags to be automatically run when I do a scons.  I have a [custom builder based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796195/232794) that allows me to run ctags from within my SConscript file.  This works in as far as I get a `tags` file in the appropriate directory.  However, since the builder runs within the root directory and not the subdirectory, I get the wrong paths (aka from the root, not the subdirectory) for all the files contains within the `tags` file.  Apart from using `sed` to strip paths in the tags file, anyone can offer a suggestion as to how to make scons generate the right paths?

**In effects, I would like to run the builder in a *specific directory* (aka the one where the SConscript is located, maybe passed as an option?) and not from the project root.**

Comment: Can you give some more details about the path problems, and perhaps a snippet of the SConscript. You can use the # character to specify paths relative to the root of the project.

Comment: Use '#' to make path from root of project (e.g. SConstruct placed).

Comment: @Brady: The code is pretty much the same as the one in the linked answer but with `epydoc` replaced by `ctags`. Yes, I know, I should write it all more generic. Bad me. No cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the builder code I ended up using.  Notice that the ctags command has a `--tag-relative=yes` option to it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import SCons.Builder
import SCons.Action

def complain_ctags(target, source, env):
    print 'INFORMATION: ctags binary was not found (see above). Tags have not been built.'

def generate(env):
    env['CTAGS'] = find_ctags(env)
    if env['CTAGS'] != None:
        #env['CTAGSCOM'] = 'cd $TARGET.dir; ctags -R .'
        env['CTAGSCOM'] = '$CTAGS --tag-relative=yes -f $TARGET $SOURCES'
        env['BUILDERS']['ctags'] = SCons.Builder.Builder(action=env['CTAGSCOM'])
    else:
        env['BUILDERS']['ctags'] = SCons.Builder.Builder(action=env.Action(complain_ctags))

def find_ctags(env):
    b=env.WhereIs('ctags')
    if b == None:
        print 'Searching for ctags: not found. Tags will not be built'
    else:
        print 'Searching for ctags: ', b
    return b

def exists(env):
    if find_ctags(env) == None:
        return 0
    return 1
```

In my `Sconscript` file(s), I can now do:

```
Alias('tags', env.ctags(source=all_python_files, target='tags'))
```

The `tags` file now contains tags with path relative to the location of the tags file and not from the scons root directory.